# How do I bundle a Solaris JRE with install4j without running the install4j application on Solaris?

Tags: install4j

The JRE download wizard in install4j only offers Linux and Windows JREs.  I need to build a media file that bundles a Solaris JRE.  install4j supports building custom JRE bundles but it's JRE Bundle wizard states:

> "Please note that the JRE Bundle wizard can only create JRE bundles
>   for the platform you're running on."

This seems like a serious omission as compared to the other multi-platform install buliders (i.e. InstallAnywhere and InstallBuilder) both of which provide bundled Solaris JREs.

**Can I not just unzip/tar a Solaris JRE on my Linux build box and bundle it?  Or is there a limitation of the mechanism used to bundle it?**

Even though we support Solaris, Solaris boxes are in limited supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I not just unzip/tar a Solaris JRE on my Linux build box and bundle it?

You would have to create the tar.gz file for the bundle manually as explained [here](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/jreBundles.html) (at the bottom of the page).

However, I would rather suggest adding a requirement that Java is installed on the Solaris box. Bundling a JRE on Solaris is somewhat risky since particular JRE versions require certain OS patches.

Comment: Understood.  We go the route of ensuring our customers know they need to be at a certain patch level.  So far this is the only place where install4j isn't matching up to it's competitors. Any chance we can influence install4j to start providing Solaris bundles on their official download page like the others do?